# Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, claims-based-identity

I am trying to create a user using claim identity asp.net 
I get this error while creating claims identity user.

```
  ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser { 
                        EmailConfirmed = true, 
                        UserName = model.myUser.Email,
                        Email = model.myUser.Email ,
                        PhoneNumber = model.myUser.PhoneNumber,
                        PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
                        UserImagePath = model.myUser.UserImagePath,
                        FirstName= model.myUser.FirstName,
                        LastName = model.myUser.LastName,
                        DateOfBirth = model.myUser.DateOfBirth,
                        Culture = model.myUser.Culture,
                        Role = model.myUser.Role
                    };
```

but when the code was

```
var user= new ApplicationUser { 

                            UserName = model.myUser.Email,
                            Email = model.myUser.Email ,

                        };
```

it worked perfectly, so i want to know what is wrong

Comment: I can´t see any problem here. Maybe you may remove one property after another from your statement to limit the point of failure.

Comment: " I get this error". What error? Have you tried removing the lines one at a time to find out where the problem is?

Comment: im sorry if i wasnt clear, i get Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement, on ApplicationUser user

Comment: I guess I know what @husseinbaalbaki means, he just didn't explain himself well. It is a C# compilation error.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

You have a statement (**if** or **while**, for example), right before the code you posted, without curly braces.

For example:

```
if (somethingIsTrue) 
{    
   var user= new ApplicationUser { 
       UserName = model.myUser.Email,
       Email = model.myUser.Email ,
   };
}
```

is correct, but the code below:

```
if (somethingIsTrue) 
   var user = new ApplicationUser { 
      UserName = model.myUser.Email,
      Email = model.myUser.Email ,
   };
```

will result in CS1023: Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement.

#### UPDATE

The reason, according to [@codefrenzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2077651), is that the newly declared variable will immediately go out of scope, unless it is enclosed in a block statement, where it can be accessed from.

The compilation will pass in the following cases though.

If you only initialize a new instance of a type, without declaring a new variable:

```
if (somethingIsTrue) 
   new ApplicationUser { 
       UserName = model.myUser.Email,
       Email = model.myUser.Email ,
   };
```

or if you assign a value to an existing variable:

```
ApplicationUser user;

if (somethingIsTrue) 
   user = new ApplicationUser { 
       UserName = model.myUser.Email,
       Email = model.myUser.Email ,
   };
```

Answer (score 10):

I just had this error, and the fix was to add a curly brace to the if immediately preceding my code, and then remove it again. Visual Studio facepalm OTD.

Comment: This answer doesn't deserve the downvotes. This error sometimes occurs when it shouln't (when no new variables are declared). When VS does something unexpected like this, a solution like this can be good fix. For us a restart of VS helped solve this issue.

Comment: Same with me. VS can be haunted by the ghosts of old compilation errors sometimes and only a restart will fix it.

Comment: I just closed the file, and reopened it, didn't need to close VS.