# Embedded statement can't be a declaration or labeled statement

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a CRUD but my variable NovaGarantia doesn't work and the error appears. Now I'm trying to do the INSERT. Follow bellow my code:

```
using EDP.GestaoVarejista.MOD;

namespace EDP.GestaoVarejista.DAL.CadastrosGerais;


    public class Garantias : Base
    {
        public int Inserir(Garantia garantia)
        {
            try
            {
                using (EDPGestaoVarejistaEntities dbEntities = new EDPGestaoVarejistaEntities())

                    tb_garantias NovaGarantia = new tb_garantias
                    {
                        descrGarantia = garantia.descGarantia   
                    };
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Is `tb_garantias` a class name?

Comment: Yes,
 public partial class tb_garantias

Comment: @Leonardo Ines what's the error message you're receiving? Is it a compile-time error or a run-time error?

Comment: When i'm typing and try to make this attribution ( tb_garantias NovaGarantia = new tb_garantias).
They are underlined and the follow message appears when my mouse is over(Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
using EDP.GestaoVarejista.MOD;

namespace EDP.GestaoVarejista.DAL.CadastrosGerais;


    public class Garantias : Base
    {
        public int Inserir(Garantia garantia)
        {
            try
            {
                using (EDPGestaoVarejistaEntities dbEntities = new EDPGestaoVarejistaEntities())
                    {
                       tb_garantias NovaGarantia = new tb_garantias
                       {
                           descrGarantia = garantia.descGarantia   
                       };
                    }
            }
        }
}
```

The problem is that you do not delimit a scope for the using. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374396/embedded-statement-cannot-be-a-declaration-or-labeled-statement) goes into more details.